# laravel-filemanager настройка

Tags: laravel

есть кнопка для загрузки изображений в админке

```
<a id="filemanager" data-input="thumbnail" data-preview="holder" class="btn-upload">Добавить изображение</a>
<input type="hidden" name="present" id="thumbnail" class="" value="{{ $present->present or  '' }}">
       <div id="holder">
            @if(!empty($present->present)) <img src="{{ $present->present}}" alt="{{$present->title}}"> @endif
        </div>


$('#filemanager').filemanager('image');

'base_directory' => 'storage/app/public',
'shared_folder_name' => 'shared',
```

можно ли сделать, чтобы я видел корневую директорию( все аппки и файлы в `storage/app/public`) в загрузчике а не содержимое папки `shared_folder_name`?

Comment: блин за что минус то? если делаю пустым shared_folder_name, то загрузчик не работает + я загружаю изображение а он пихает в shared

Comment: может сталкивался кто с такой проблемой? чтобы обойтись без папки shared?